# LINQ to XML new added XElement isn't saved to XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to update an XML file but the new added `XElement` isn't saved to the XML file. When I use the debugger I can see that the new `XElement` is added to the list of `node's` but in the XML it's not there.

Relevant XML

```
<object occur="-1" prefix="Pages" table="Pages" description="Title" singlename="Pagina" name="Pagina's" statemode="disabled" link="" exportable="0">
  <views>
    <view id="1" type="tree" name="Subpagina Overzicht">
      <sql></sql>
      <model table="Pages" parent="parentID" />
      <preview textlength="50" />
    </view>
    <view id="2" type="normal" name="Overzicht">
      <sql></sql>
      <columns>
        <column description="Naam" sortnode="Title" width="" />
      </columns>
      <values></values>
    </view>
  </views>
  <objectviews>
    <view id="view1" type="view" name="Bekijken" show="1" link=""></view>
    <view id="view2" type="edit" name="Bewerken" show="1" link=""></view>
    <view id="view3" type="delete" name="Verwijderen" show="1" link=""></view>
    <view id="view4" type="add" name="Toevoegen" show="1" link=""></view>
  </objectviews>
  <nodes>
    <node id="ParentId" description="Bovenliggende pagina" required="0" datatype="i" nodetype="-2" fieldlength="" reference="Pages,Title,id" exclude="-" tab="General" order="10" default="" decimals="" maxchars="" help="" unique="" show="1" />
    <node id="Title" description="Titel" required="0" datatype="s" nodetype="" fieldlength="" reference="" exclude="" tab="General" order="10" default="" decimals="" maxchars="" help="" unique="" show="1" />
    <node id="UrlTitle" description="Url" required="0" datatype="s" nodetype="" fieldlength="" reference="" exclude="" tab="General" order="30" default="" decimals="" maxchars="" help="Leeg laten zorgt voor een automatische url, gebaseerd op Naam" unique="" show="0" />
    <node id="Content" description="Inhoud" required="0" datatype="s" nodetype="-3" fieldlength="" reference="" exclude="" tab="General" order="40" default="" decimals="" maxchars="" help="" unique="" show="1" />
    <node id="Sorting" description="Sorting" required="0" datatype="i" nodetype="-6" fieldlength="" reference="" exclude="" tab="General" order="100" default="" decimals="" maxchars="" help="" unique="" show="0" />
    <node id="SeoTitle" description="Pagina titel" required="0" datatype="s" nodetype="" fieldlength="" reference="" exclude="" tab="Seo" order="10" default="" decimals="" maxchars="" help="" unique="" show="1" />
    <node id="SeoDescription" description="Description" required="0" datatype="s" nodetype="" fieldlength="" reference="" exclude="" tab="Seo" order="20" default="" decimals="" maxchars="" help="" unique="" show="1" />
    <node id="SeoKeywords" description="Keywords" required="0" datatype="s" nodetype="" fieldlength="" reference="" exclude="" tab="Seo" order="30" default="" decimals="" maxchars="" help="" unique="" show="1" />
  </nodes>
  <tabs>
    <tab id="General" order="10" type="normal" child="" foreignkey="" description="Algemeen" link="" />
    <tab id="Seo" order="20" type="normal" child="" foreignkey="" description="SEO" link="" />
    <tab id="Blocks" order="30" type="child" child="ContentBlocks" foreignkey="PageId" description="Content blokken" link="" />
    <!--<tab id="SubPages" order="40" type="child" child="Pages" foreignkey="PageId" description="Subpagina's" link=""/>-->
    <tab id="Attachments" order="50" type="attachments" child="" foreignkey="" description="Bijlage" link="" />
  </tabs>
  <attachments>
    <attachment id="attachment1" show="1" required="0" tab="Attachments" width="1000" height="1000" type="image" description="Afbeelding" userdescription="0" help="" internal="0" />
  </attachments>
</object>
```

Relevant Code

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    //check if the table name exists as the prefix of an object element in the instellingen.xml
    var query = from node in doc.Descendants("object")
                where node.Attribute("prefix").Value == row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString()
                select node.Element("nodes");



    //if the node is found
    if (query.Count() != 0)
    {
        var desecendants = query.Descendants("node").ToList();

        PropertyInfo[] properties = propDict[row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString()];


        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            int index = desecendants.FindIndex(item => item.Attribute("id").Value == prop.Name);
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                //Property is in list
                //TODO: check for property position changes 
            }
            else
            {
               doc.Root.Descendants("object").Where(objectnode => objectnode.Attribute("prefix").Value == row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString()).Elements("nodes").Descendants("node").ToList()
                /*desecendants*/.Add(new XElement("node",
                              new XAttribute("id", prop.Name),
                              new XAttribute("description", String.Empty),
                              new XAttribute("required", String.Empty),
                              new XAttribute("datatype", String.Empty), //could be auto generated
                              new XAttribute("nodetype", String.Empty),
                              new XAttribute("fieldlength", String.Empty),
                              new XAttribute("reference", String.Empty), 
                              new XAttribute("exclude", String.Empty),
                              new XAttribute("tab", String.Empty),
                              new XAttribute("order", String.Empty),
                              new XAttribute("default",String.Empty),
                              new XAttribute("decimals", String.Empty),
                              new XAttribute("maxchars",String.Empty),
                              new XAttribute("help", String.Empty),
                              new XAttribute("unique",String.Empty),
                              new XAttribute("show",String.Empty)));

            }
        }

    }
}

doc.Save(@"C:/instellingen.xml");
```

`descendants` contains the `node's` of the `nodes`tag in the XML file. I tried adding the `XElement` to `descendants` and to the `doc.Root` but the element isn't saved to the XML. How can I fix this?

EDIT

Fixed it by adding to the `XElement` to

```
doc.Root.Descendants("object").Where(objectnode =>  objectnode.Attribute("prefix").Value == row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString()).Elements("nodes").LastOrDefault()
```

Comment: I think you converted it ToList(), which creates another collection and you are actually adding new item to that collection, while the 'doc' is not getting affected. When it is going to be save, just before that, check if 'doc' have that newly added element ?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you could provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Currently we have a lot of code which isn't terribly relevant, but not enough to actually reproduce the issue.

Comment: @MuhammadIdrees how can I add the new element without the `ToList()`